# How to build buffers for each polygon, which requires the buffer area approximately equal the polygon area in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, buffer

I want to build buffers for each irregular polygon in featurecollections in Google Earth Engine. The buffer area is required to approximately equal the polygon area. I am very new to GEE.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a "established" way to compute buffer in GEE based on obtaining approximately equal area. Well "approximate" is kind of a loose term but I have gotten more than 1.9 in area of buffered feature and original feature for differently shaped feature with this method.

First, we assume a regular rectangle and try to calculate the buffered area based on that.
It should be

> original perimeter X buffer distance + 4 x (buffer distance)^2

and that should be equal to the area of the original feature. Since that is a simple quadratic equation, solving that gave me

> buffer distance = ( -p + sqrt(p^2 +16a))/8

taking only positive values coz we know we want to grow the feature. So i put that formula in gee. You can see the full code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d3303ac53d880593367b9cc7cb95a5a9)

```
function bufferequal(feature){
  var ar = feature.area();
  var perim = feature.perimeter();

  var rooted = perim.pow(2).add(ar.multiply(16)).sqrt();
  var nomin = rooted.subtract(perim);

  var soln = nomin.divide(8);

  var buff = feature.buffer(soln);

  return buff;
}
```

The next thing for your question should be how to apply this to each feature of a feature collection. That would be to use this function as a mapping function as follows.

```
var bufferedCollection = yourFeatureCollection.map(bufferequal);
```

Once again, this WILL NOT give you exactly equal area but since you said you wanted approximate area, i like this method over the iterative methods.

Comment: Nice approximation! When mapping over a featureCollection, don't forget casting the input to a feature and getting the geometry() from that feature: https://code.earthengine.google.com/85d9ccc31b229cb991cfe82c91d05043